# How to restart the timer after using deltaTIme

Tags: unity, c#

I am creating a simple game interface. When `fillAmount > 0`, the timer is stopped and reset. I want to restart the timer if the fill amount does not change for 3 seconds. All the code does now is counting 3 seconds and then displaying the time when it stops. How do I fix it?

```
private float startTime;
private float reStartTime;
public Barscript barscripts;

void Start() {
    startTime = Time.time
    DefaultImg = GetComponent<Image>();
}

void Update() {
    float t = Time.time - startTime;
    reStartTime = 3;
    float t1 = reStartTime - startTime;

    string hours = ((int) t / 6).ToString();
    string minutes = ((t % 6) * 10).ToString();

    Debug.Log(barscripts.fillAmount);
    
    if (batscripts.fillAmount > 0) {
        DefaultImg.sprite = Emoji3;
        startTime += Time.deltatime;
        timerText.text = " 0   :   00 "
        Debug.Log(t1);

        if (t1 < 0) {
            timerText.text = hours + "   :   " + minutes;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d0JH.jpg) of what I'm getting at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to create a time counter with deltaTime, it is easy like this:

```
float timeRunning =0.0f;
Update()
{
   timeRunning += Time.deltaTime;
   if(timeRunning >= 3.0f)
   {
   //Do things
   timeRunning = 0.0f; //Restart counting
   }
}
```

Inside the do things you could check the fillAmout's value with an older value (you should create a `lastFillAmount` variable)

Comment: If this is for quick repetition of timing, such as with rapid fire of projectiles, it may be useful to decrement 'timeRunning' by 'deltaTime' rather than set it to '0'. This way you are not losing out on what is potentially a noticeable portion of your accumulated time.

Comment: Instead of using the Update() method, maybe make 2 coroutine methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should do what you want, its quite self-explanatory but if you have any question just don't hesitate to ask.

```
private float _lastFillAmountChangeTime;
private float _fillAmount;
private float _timer;

public float FillAmount
{
    get {  return _fillAmount;}
    set
    {
        // register the change if input value != current value
        if(value != _fillAmount)
        {
            _lastFillAmountChangeTime = UnityEngine.Time.time;
        }
        _fillAmount = value;
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    // give these fields initial values
    _lastFillAmountChangeTime = 0;
    _fillAmount = 0;
    _timer = 0;
}

private void Update ()
{
    // update timer 
    _timer += UnityEngine.Time.deltaTime;

    // its more than 3 sec from the last change of FillAmount
    if (_lastFillAmountChangeTime + 3 < UnityEngine.Time.time) 
    {
        // reset the timer
        _timer = 0;
    }
}
```